# sum string with number onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a global variable :

```
var a;
```

I put my onclick function into my html div in concatenation **PHP** :

```
$number =' <div onclick="select(this,'."'250000'".');" > ';
$number .= ...etc...  //php function
$number .='</div>';
```

to insert string into div value onclick (**button**) :

```
function select (price){
if ($(id).attr('class') == "table2") { //unselect button
    $(id).attr('class', 'table1');
    var price2=document.getElementById("price").value.split(",");
    var removePrice = price;;
    var price3 = jQuery.grep(price2, function (value) { return value != removePrice;});
    document.getElementById("price").value = price3;
    if (n.length == 0) i = 0;
} else {
    $(id).attr('class', 'table2'); //select button
    if (i == 0) {
        document.getElementById("price").value = price;
        a = Number(document.getElementById("price").value); //assign the value into a
        i = 1;  
    } else {
        $(id).attr('class','table3');
    }  
}
```

---

From there, I have checkbox **HTML** :

```
<div id="CourseMenu"><input type="checkbox" value="50000" />&nbsp Ekstra Bed <input type="checkbox" value="50000"  />&nbsp Breakfast</div>
```

After that I have **another** function to sum 2 div value (**checkbox**) :

```
$(function($) {
  var sum = 0;
  $('#CourseMenu :checkbox').click(function() { sum = 0;
    $('#CourseMenu :checkbox:checked').each(function(idx, elm) {
        sum += parseInt(elm.value, 10);
    });
    var b  = parseInt(a||0, 10) + parseInt(sum||0, 10); 
    $('#sum').html(b); //<--resulted NaN when sum with button
    document.getElementById("price").value=b; //<-- assign b as div value
  });
});
```

---

The purpose is to sum the total price (**button & checkbox**) into div value

```
<input type="hidden" id="price" name="price" value="" />
```

---

it works fine when the function sum only the **checkbox**, but when I try to show the sum with the **button** (global variable) it resulted in NaN

I think I already convert the string into number there, is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: `var value = document.getElementById("price").value * 1`

Comment: Also, don't mix jquery `$("#..` with javascript `document.getElementById(`.

Comment: It's most likely `a` (nice variable name...) is already `NaN` before it gets to your sum function.  Can you make a fiddle showing it not working?

Comment: Where is `select` - Please show more HTML and relevant scripts

Comment: check the type of `a` before adding.. `typeof(a)`

Comment: @arumuga-why the type of a is undefined ?.......

Comment: is your `a` value set correctly?

Comment: even after I click the button(assign the string), still undefined type

Comment: Is the var a inside an onload like this: `$(function() { var a; });` ? Please show ALL relevant code and HTML - also the "simplified" does not make sense

Comment: Have a look at my answer. It should contain the logic you need and eliminate the issues you have if you can implement it in your code

Comment: from where does the id come in `if($(id).at`

Comment: This is wrong too: `function select(price){` it would work somewhat better if you did `function select(div,price){` and have `<div onclick="select(this,250000)">`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem in passing the arguments in onclick event:
onclick="select(this,'250000');" => passing this as first argument try changing to onclick="select('250000')";

but your select function is expecting string as the first argument:

```
function select(price){ //<-- simplified
   document.getElementById("price").value=price;
   a = Number(document.getElementById("price").value); 
}
```

Comment: You mean the function is passing (this,number) so it is adding the field to the field value - I think we need to see what "simplified" means

Answer (score 0):

Here is an actual solution for your X/Y problem.

The code will initialise the field and clicking buttons or checking checkboxes work independently.

```js
function calc() {
  var sum = parseInt($("#price").text(), 10);
  $('#CourseMenu :checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    sum += parseInt(this.value, 10);
  });
  $('#sum').val(sum);
}
$(function() {
  $("#CourseMenu .btn").on("click", function() {
    $("#price").text($(this).data("price")); // using the data attribute
    calc(); 
  });
  $('#CourseMenu input:checkbox').on("click",function() { 
    calc(); // 
  });
  calc(); // initialise in case the page is reloaded.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="CourseMenu">
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-price="25000">25000</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-price="35000">35000</button>
  <div id="price">0</div>

  <br/>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="200" />200</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="300" />300</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="400" />400</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="text" id="sum" value="" />
</form>
```

PS: If you do nothing else on click of checkboxes, you can write

```
  $('#CourseMenu input:checkbox').on("click",calc);
```